# Unable to GET url data into model class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I have a table that shows a count of all the statuses of a product. Now these counts are clickable and lead to another page that shows the in detail data of whatever item that was clicked. I'm able to get this data by putting it in the URL using

```
<a target='_blank' href='".site_url('reports/lists?source=' . $title . '&status=' . $status) . "'>
```

This correctly puts the data for the product that I had clicked in the URL.
Now I'm trying to get this data from the URL and accordingly filter the data according to the values that are present in the URL, but I cannot get the value from to URL to filter it even after I've used `$leadsource = $this->input->get('status');`

View Class:

```
<?php  
$sess=$this->session->userdata(); 
$post = array('fstatus'=> $sess['fstatus'],'fsource'=> $sess['fsource']);
$postd = json_encode(array_filter($post));
$leadstatus = $this->input->get('source');
?>
<table id="item-list">
            <tr> 
                <th>Ref.No#</th>
                <th>Source</th>
            </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function sendreq(){
    setpostdatas();cleartable();getleads();
  }

   var userrole = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('clientrole')?>";
   var leadsource = "<?php echo $leadsource ?>";
   var slug = '<?php echo $slug?>';
   var postd = '<?php echo $postd; ?>';
if( userrole > 1 && userrole != 5){
    $('#item-list').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering": false,
          "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex){
            $(row).has( "div.overdueupdate" ).css('background-color','#FFC7CE');
              },
        "ajax": {
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>reports/loadLeads",
            data: {slug: slug, postdata: postd, leadsource: leadsource},
            type : 'POST',
            "dataSrc": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
                if(d.recordsTotal == 0 || d.data == null){
                   $("#item-list_info").text("No records found");
                    $("#item-list_processing").css("display","none");
                }
                return d.data;
            }
        },
        'columns': [
            {"data": "id", "id": "id"},
            {"data": "refno", "refno": "refno"},
            {"data": "source", "source": "source"},   
        ]
    });
  }
```

Controller Class:

```
public function loadLeads($p=''){
        $leadsource = $this->input->get('status');
        if(isset($_POST['postdata'])){
            if($_POST['postdata'] != null && $_POST['postdata'] != 'null'){
                $post=$_POST['postdata'];
            }
            $post = json_decode($post,true);
            unset($post['slug']);
            unset($post['page']);
            $sort = $post['afsort'];
            if($sort == "asc"){
                $sortQ = 'l.updated_date asc,';
            }else if ($sort == "desc"){
                $sortQ = 'l.updated_date desc,';
            }
        }
        $offset = (int)$_POST['start'] ;
        $pstdatas = explode(',', $_POST['postdata']);
        unset($pstdatas['item-list_length']);
        if($this->session->userdata('clientrole') == 1 || $this->session->userdata('clientrole') == 5 ){
            $content['leads']=$this->leads_model->get_pagination($_POST['length'],$offset,$where,'',false,$sortQ?$sortQ:'l.assign_status =\'Unassigned\' desc,',$all,$leadsource);          
        }else{
            $content['leads']=$this->leads_model->get_pagination($_POST['length'],$offset,$where,'',false,$sortQ?$sortQ:'l.assigned_date desc,',$all,$leadsource);
        }

public function lists($slug='')
    {
        $this->load->model(array('crm/crm_model'));  
        $content['propertyrefnos']=$this->crm_model->property_refnos();
        $content['is_mobile'] = $this->ismob;
        $content['sources']= $this->sources_model->get_active(array(),'id,title','title asc' );
      }
```

Model Class:

```
function get_pagination($num, $offset, $cond='',$order='',$unlimit=false,$add_order='',$all='',$leadsource)
    {
        $this->db->select("l.*");
        $sess=$this->session->userdata(); 
        if(is_array($cond) && count($cond)>0){ $this->db->where($cond); }

        if(empty($cond)){           
            if($sess['afstatus']==''){
                $leadsource = $this->input->get('status');
                if($searchdata['keyword'] !='' || $searchdata['fstatus'] !='' || $searchdata['fproject'] || $searchdata['fdevelop'] || $all != ''){
                $this->db->where_in('lead_status',array(1,8,9,2,3,4,10,11)); 
                $this->db->where('lead_source',$leadsource);
                }
                else            {
                $this->db->where_in('lead_status',array(1,8,9,11));
                $this->db->where('lead_source',$leadsource);}
                }
        }
....
$query =  $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Here as you can see I've tried adding `$leadsource = $this->input->get('status');` in my controller class and my model, but none of them return me the url data that I want. But putting this code under my lists function controller returns me the data from the URL, but I want it to happen in my loadLeads function.

I've added the following in my loadleads controller and the output of source is always null:

```
        $output = array(
            "source" => $leadsource,
            "data" => $data 
        );

        echo json_encode($output); 
        exit();
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What does `$leadsource` contain?

Comment: `$leadsource` should contain my URL data. So as of now if my url is `http://localhost/reports/lists?source=Product1&status=4`, then leadsource should contain `Product1`. Now this works when I add this statement in my lists controller, but it does not work when it is added to my loadLeads controller. This is where I'm stuck at

Comment: And **what** does `$leadsource` contain? Don't guess, don't explain, dump it

Comment: Yes I have done var_dump($leadsource) in my lists controller and loadLeads controller. It shows up when it is in lists controller, but not when it is in loadLeads. When I try to put it in loadleads and refresh the page it gives `DataTables warning: table id=item-list - Invalid JSON response.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the parameters in your controller, not in your modal.

```
$leadsource = $this->input->get('status');
```

And because this parameters are passed through the URL, you have to access them using `$_GET`.

```
public function loadLeads($p=''){
     $leadsource = $this->input->get('status');

     // your other controller codes here
}
```

Comment: When I try to put it in loadleads and refresh the page it gives `DataTables warning: table id=item-list - Invalid JSON response`.